# mongodb node, как сделать вложенные объекты?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть структура:

```
var ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type : String, required : true },
    domainid: { type : String, required : true },
    requests: {
        request: { type: String }
    },
    active: { type : Boolean, required : true }
});
```

Как можно сделать чтобы request Был отдельным объектом внутри текущего, и чтобы можно было их создавать сколько угодно request внутри текущего объекта коллекции?

Answer (score 2):

## Вариант 1.

```
requests: [{
    request: { type: String }
}],
```

Согласно этой схеме `requests` - массив объектов с заданной структурой (с одним ключом `request` и строковым значением).

## Вариант 2.

```
requests: [String],
```

Тут `requests` - массив строк, если вам не нужен лишний ключ, и нужны лишь строки